# Can't get to work localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, stringify

I've tried to get a save function getting triggered by a button to work but when I search on every storage possible i don't find anything so I need to know what I'm doing wrong or what lacks the code

```js
function savewm(){
 var save = {
     plus1: plus1,
 }
 localStorage.setItem('save', JSON.stringify(savewn));
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `save !== savewn` And is `plus1` defined?

Comment: I see your problem... Your not looking at the console.

Comment: fixed the savewn, plus1 is like this:
var plus1 = Math.pow(10, -3);

Answer (score 0):

You mistakenly stored **savewn** which is a function instead of the **save** object.

Also, plus1 is undefined which will cause an error.

You could try this to work.

```
function savewm(){
var save = {
    plus1: 'test1',
}
localStorage.setItem('save', JSON.stringify(save));
};
```

Comment: `savewm` is the function, `savevn` is not declared in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you to find out if it is really saved is using the localStorage.getItem(). If getItem returns you something, it is saved. Then the problem would be, you probably looked at the wrong place with your browser.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('save'));
```